# why is part of my mesh clear in solid view port even though in the render view it is white diffuse?

Tags: rendering, mesh

how do i make the clear part opaque again?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you deleted faces in that area and left only vertices and edges. Another possibility is that they were somehow hidden, try to press Alt+H to unhide all in Edit mode. It also seems that there are either overlaps in geometry or clipping problems, from wording of your question it's not clear what exactly do you ask

Comment: oh its fixed now thanks! alt-h in edit mode did it

Comment: I guess if this is the correct answer it would be helpfull to write it as an answer and mark the question closed? :)

Comment: Anyone can write the answer. @cheddarshark you can write one in the Answer box below and show some screenshots and / or short explanation of what and how you did. Then you can accept it to show the system and others answer s solved

Comment: it says i can "accept my own answer in 2 days" so do i just wait until then?

Answer (score 1):

i pressed alt h in edit mode and that fixed it

[image]